# Lets encrypt certificate renew: PluginError occured

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, apache2, lets-encrypt

I am trying to renew the letsencrypt SSL certificate in the `apache` by using the following command.

`sudo certbot renew`

But I am getting the following error

> error was: PluginError('There has been an error in parsing the file
>   /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf on line 46: Syntax
>   error',). Skipping.

Certbot version: `0.25.0`
Os: Ubuntu

Here is the line from `000-default.conf` that indicates in the error message

```
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Please execute: apache2ctl configtest is result OK?

Comment: I am getting this error while running the command `AH00526: Syntax error on line 31 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem' does not exist or is empty` But the file is still exists

Answer (score 0):

> # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

Lines beginning with a `#` are comments. That line is a comment, you can safely remove it from the file.